# How can I design a Butterworth filter with python specifying that my cutoff frequency is 0.1 Hz?

Tags: python, scipy, frequency, butterworth

Here I am trying to create a highpass butterworth digital filter with a cutoff frequency at 0.1 Hz.
I had implemented the following code and I am not sure if it is true

```
#%% creating the filter 
# filter parameters 
order=6
btype='highpass'
cutoff_frequency=0.1*2*np.pi
analog=False

b, a= signal.butter(order,cutoff_frequency,btype, analog)
w, h = signal.freqs(b, a)

plt.figure() 
plt.plot(w, 20 * np.log10(abs(h)))
plt.xscale('log')
plt.title('Butterworth filter frequency response')
plt.xlabel('Frequency [radians / second]')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude [dB]')
plt.margins(0, 0.1)
plt.grid(which='both', axis='both')
plt.axvline(0.1*2*np.pi, color='green') # cutoff frequency
plt.show()
```

My confusion is about the cutoff frequency here I multiplied it by 2*pi because as I understood the cutoff_frequency of scipy.signal.butter corresponds to an angular frequency in rad/s.

Comment: The filter frequency is (by default) a normalized fraction of the Nyqvist frequency, not an absolutely frequency

Comment: but it is in rand/second and I want to implement 0.1 Hz so I need to multiply it by 2*pi no?

Comment: No it has no dimensions by default. It is a fraction of the Nyqvist frequency. There is (in newer scipy versions) an optional sampling frequency argument, in which case the frequency is in the same units as the sampling frequency, otherwise it is just a non-dimensional value

Comment: So I just need to put 0.1 and it corresponds to 0.1 Hz no?

Comment: No. You need to calculate a non-dimensional frequency from the Nyqvist frequency of your system (0.1Hz/Nyqvist frequency in Hz)

Comment: My sampling rate is 1Hz so my Nyqvist frequency in Hz is 1Hz/2 no? and then I need to do 0.1Hz/0.5Hz no?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing that my sampling frequency is 1Hz I have performed the following steps to design the highpass 6th order Butterworth digital filter with a cutoff frequency at 0.1 Hz:

```
order=6 # order of the filter
btype='highpass' # type
F_sampling=1.0   # my sampling freq
Nyqvist_freq=F_sampling/2 # Nyqvist frequency in function of my sampling frequency
cut_off_Hz=0.1 # my cutoff frequency in Hz
cutoff_frequency=cut_off_Hz/Nyqvist_freq    # normalized cut_off frequency
analog=False #digital filter
b, a= signal.butter(order,cutoff_frequency,btype, analog)
w, h = signal.freqs(b, a)
Detrend_carrierPhase=signal.filtfilt(b, a, Carrier_phase) # filtering my high rate carrier phase
```

I am using the scipy library where the cut_off frequency is a fraction of the Nyqvist frequency and it is a non-dimensional value that's why I need to transform my sampling frequency expressed in Hz to the Nyqvist freq through dividing it by 2, so it is equal to 1Hz/2 =0.5 Hz it is the Nyqvist frequency of my system. The normalized Nyqvist cut_off freq given to the butter filter is 0.1 (Cut_off frequency in Hz) divided by 0.5 (Nyqvist frequency of my system).

I used the signal.filtfilt to filter my carrier phase (signal)

Hope this will be helpful!